# What is the definition of $I=(f(X,Y),g(X,Y))$?

Tags: definition, ideals

What is the definition of this ideal in $\mathbb C[X,Y]\ I=(f(X,Y),g(X,Y))$ for some polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb C[X,Y]$

Comment: The $\,R$-ideal $(a,b)\,$ denotes $\,aR + bR\, =\, \{ar + bs\ :\ r,s\in R\},\,$ for a commutative ring $R.\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the ideal generated by $f$ an $g$, i.e. any polynomial in teh ideal has the form $a(x,y)f(x,y)+b(x,y)g(x,y)$ for $a,b$ any polynomials in your ring.